# Loop over numpy array to save them as tif files

Tags: python, loops, numpy, tiff

I am trying to save a numpy array (train_images) with shape (625, 256, 256, 4) as tif images in a folder using a for loop. That is, 625 RGBN images of 256 x 256 pixels. Currently my code looks as follows:

```
path = str(os.getcwd) + "/data/train_images"

for i in train_images:
    num = 0
    i.save(num + '.tif')
    num +=1
```

It is however not possible to save a numpy array as a tif file like this. In the end I would like to have 625 saved (RGBN) tif images in the folder named 0.tif, 1.tif etc.

Comment: `train_images` is not defined.

Comment: I'm sorry, train_images is the numpy array of shape (625, 256, 256, 4).

Comment: Maybe you want to look into the `tifffile` module https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/ because `numpy.save` does "Save an array to a binary file in NumPy .npy format". Keep in mind that a TIFF file contains a header.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: @TeeKea "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save'"

Comment: @DanielF Yes using tifffile is good advice, can't find the right code for my problem though...

Comment: @Eeuwigestudent1 do you have `scipy` installed? In that case TeeKea's answer is a better solution. For examples on `tifffile` see https://github.com/blink1073/tifffile#examples BTW, `scipy` uses `PIL` for storing images, you may also want to look into `PIL` (or pillow)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I will look into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `imsave` in `scipy.misc`, as follows:

```
path = str(os.getcwd) + "/data/train_images/"

num = 0
for img in train_images:
    import scipy.misc
    scipy.misc.imsave(path + str(num)  + '.tif', img)
    num +=1
```

To read an image from a file, you would need to use the following:

```
import imageio
im = imageio.imread('0.tif')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please Tick mark the answer as **Accepted**.

Comment: Just did, tried to upvote you but don't have enough reputation (yet). Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. Good luck.

Comment: There is one problem though, if I read the image in again the shape has changed. When we loop over the train images then "train_image" has shape (625,256,256,4), and when i read the saved images they have shape (25, 256, 256, 4). Where does this first 25 come from?

Comment: I see. Can you please show the code you used to read the saved images?

Comment: Can you read them using `im = imageio.imread('0.tif')`. You'll need to `import imageio`

Comment: Aaaand you did it again. All is good now, thanks for the third time!